# magento 2 catalog_product_save_before unable to save product

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, event-observer

I'm trying to save the product in the observer of event "catalog_product_save_before", but somehow the admin panel is just loading its not saving product.

Can anyone please suggest the solution for this?

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="catalog_product_save_before">
    <observer name="test_updateproductsku_observer_backend_catalog_productsavebefore_catalog_product_save_before" instance="Iflair\Updateproductname\Observer\Backend\Catalog\ProductSaveBefore"/>
</event>
```

```
public function execute(
    \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
) {
    $_product = $observer->getProduct(); // you will get product object
    $_sku = $_product->getSku(); // for sku
    $_product->setSku("testNew1");
    $_product->save();
}
```

Comment: could you plz add code you have tried ? did you checked var/log ?

Comment: it is keep loading, not adding anything to log

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have observed the `"catalog_product_save_before"` event and again trying to save the product. So `$_product->save()` code again observe your event and it runs your observer as a loop. If you want to change any attribute value you can just set the data and let it. It will automatically save your changes.

So just remove the `$_product->save()` line and then try to save the product, it will work.